# How to use SqlDataSource for filling combobox as well as datatable or Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding, sqldatasource

I am trying to fetch a column value from a datasource when some value is selected from a dropdownlist on its change event.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCityName"  runat="server" DataSourceID="dsCity" 
    DataTextField="CityName" DataValueField="CityID" AutoPostBack="True"
    OnTextChanged="CityName_OnTextChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCity" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GmapConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vcity]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here I want to fetch any other column's value that is not binded to a ddlCityName from sqldatasource.

I have four columns in datasource i.e. name, id, address, phno.

I want to fetch an address of a person who selects some value from ddl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you can do that, but what I use in this situation is this, I combine my values together and add them all to the value field of DDList, for example you want ID and Address, so add them like this in your select query :
select Cast(id as varchar) + '##' + address ....
you can use any separator that you think will be unique, then just simply split the value string.